# Printing all elements of a list next to another string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that printing all elements of a string has been asked and answered many times, but I'm having trouble finding a solution for doing that in-line, and next to another statement.

I have the following setup:

```
api_endpoints = ['candidate', 'employee']

print(*api_endpoints, sep=', ')
# candidate, employee

print('Getting data for: ', *api_endpoints, sep=', ')
# Getting data for: , candidate, employee
```

But I would like the desired output to be: `Getting data for: candidate, employee`

Without altering the list, how do I print this statement like I want it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `.join()` to build your string :

```
api_endpoints = ['candidate', 'employee']
print('Getting data for: ' + ', '.join(api_endpoints))
```

Or do some overkill by redirecting `print()` output and store it in a variable which you can then use where ever you want:

```
from io import StringIO
import sys

result = StringIO()

# redirect to 'result'
sys.stdout = result

api_endpoints = ['candidate', 'employee']
print(*api_endpoints, sep=', ', end='')

# reset back
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
print('Getting data for: ' + result.getvalue())
```

output :

```
Getting data for: candidate, employee
```

Answer (score 2):

Just adding this to very valid previous answers.

Assuming you are in Python 3.6+. You can do something like this using [string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) which I've found to be very useful.

```py
print(f"Getting data for: {', '.join(api_endpoints)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as:

```
",".join(api_endpoints)
```